# Listening to multiple JRadioButtons with one actionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I have two JRadioButtons that will be used to sort objects in a JList in various ways. They are both members of the same ButtonGroup. However, I'd like to listen to both buttons with one actionlistener and then iterate through them to see which one was selected. What is the most effecient way of doing such?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is using [ButtonGroup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html)'s [getSelection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getSelection%28%29), which returns the [ButtonModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) of the [JRadioButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) that is selected. Your [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) should be able to distinguish which one is selected by examining this.

Comment: but be sure to check if the returned ButtonModel is null (if no JRadioButton has yet been selected) first before getting its actionCommand

Answer (score 1):

The ActionListener tells you which button was clicked in the ActionEvent:

```
JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton)event.getSource();
```

Comment: You add the ActionListener to both buttons.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got mixed up and didn't really think that through. Again, thanks for the input!